# issue to send text using jquery's $.ajax() and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, json, jquery, types

I use to work with the animation on jquery but never ajax, so it's my first experience with $.ajax() function of jquery:

I am trying to make my web application only using jquert library, I checked over the web for a good tutorial to make asp.net and jquery work, and I found an walkthrought, in this article they send a int to an WebMethod and it work for me, but in my case I want to send String and/or objects.

I know the issue is int the datatype and/or contentType.
here is my code sample.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#name").change(function() {
    var myname = this.value;
    var options = {
      type: "POST",
      url: "dollarajax.aspx/hello",
      data: "{nom:" + myname + "}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.d != "") {
          alert(response.d);
          $("#name").focus();
        }
      }
    };
    $.ajax(options);
  });
});
</script>
```

---

```
[WebMethod]
public static string hello(String nom)
{        
    return ("hello my friend: " + nom);
}
```

so any idea or any document where i can figure the trick to make it work?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the data like this:

```
data: '{"nom":"'+ myname +'"}',
```

instead of:

```
data: "{nom:" + myname + "}",
```

Comment: but that mean that i have to parse every single parametre to it format in the back end.
thanks it's working!

Comment: You can also add the JSON parser from http://www.json.org/json2.js which has a stringify method for this if it is NOT in your browser.
Here is the page with a minified version as well: http://www.json.org/js.html